# How do I make my character hold his face and stay that way even when the rig moves?

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

How do I make my character hold his face (he's covering his eyes) even when the character moves, like covering an injury? See the example picture.
I've tried child constraining the rig to the mesh, but it doesn't work. My character seems doing parkour when I tried that.

[image: example position with hand on face]

I want the hand to stay on the face, but when I move the body the hand doesn't follow. I've been using object constraint. How do I make the hand always stick to the face?

[image: head/body moved back without hand, so face is now uncovered]

Edit: I have now solved this by using the child to select the hand bone (be sure to select the bone constraint) and selecting the mesh.

Answer (score 4):

Give your hand controller a *Child Of* constraint with the head as target. Maybe you'll need to enable the *IK Solver > iTaSC* in the *Object Data panel > Inverse Kinematics* if you see that the elbow goes mad. Now when you'll move the body the hand will stick to the head:

[image]